# How to report returned Roth IRA contributions and earnings in H&R Block software

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira

I'm using H&R Block software for my 2019 taxes. I am over 60 and was successfully able to withdraw my 2019 Roth IRA contributions.  (My MAGI is too high.)

The tax software indicates I will need to override the shown entries for 1040-lines 4a and 4b. This makes some sense and  I see that this override can be done manually -- however, the software indicates that a manual override will prohibit e-filing.

So my question: Is there anywhere else in the software where the returned 2019 contributions and earnings can be entered so that it is both added to the line 1040-lines 4a,4b totals and allow me to e-file?

Comment: Why do you need to override? Did you get a 1099-R for the correction(s)? Does it have the correct amounts in box 1 and 2a? Did you enter those, and did they flow through to the 1040? If you rightclick and choose "Jump to related" you should be able to find the source it is using, which should ultimately be based on manual or at least mixed (auto-pull/manual) input.

Comment: I needed to withdraw my excess 2019 IRA contribution, but that wasn't done until 2020,  It looks like an override is the only way to enter the show the withdrawal -- and the taxable earnings on that contribution -- in my 2019 returns,

Comment: I've never needed to do an early-next-year correction, but I think the custodian should send you a 1099-R; try asking them. (For an early-next-year _contribution_ I definitely know they send a new or revised 5498, about a month after the deadline.) If they won't, personally I would lie to the software and claim I did get a 1099-R containing the correct figures; that is definitely allowed in other cases where the payor sometimes doesn't actually send the form, like interest under $10. Good luck.